# Recreating a game for learning purposes : what's that feature?

Tags: android, animation, 2d, game-physics, godot

I picked up Godot a week ago and I am recreating apps to get good at developing, which works fine. But sometimes there's a little feature I am obsessive about and can't figure out. You can see the trail of the ball in the Android game Dune in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukqAJBG_mMM) video. It's some kind of animation, that obeys the laws of physics. I tried particles and although it serves the purpose, the outcome is by far not the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't have to obey any laws of physics - it is simply a graphical representation of the location history of the object. Please elaborate on how the particle attempt was "by far not the same"; it could be that you are not making the particles fade away with time, or applying physics to them.

Comment: I answered to your comment, because of too many characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As meowgoesthedog already mentioned, the trail is simply a location history and does not do any physics processing. That is all done by the ball and the history will automatically reflect this.

To answer how you get one solid trail instead of disconnected particles you will have to draw a polygon. Look at [custom drawing in 2d](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/tutorials/2d/custom_drawing_in_2d.html) how to do this, and then at [the actual method to draw a polygon](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_canvasitem.html#class-canvasitem-draw-colored-polygon).

To get the points of your polygon you iterate your location history from small to big, and add each point + its radius in the y direction. Make sure the first radius is 0 and include the current position of the ball. Then you iterate the location history from big to small and you add each point - its radius in the y direction. The result is that you trace the upper edge first, then jump down to the lower edge, but this should be hidden by the actual ball. Then you trace the lower edge and meet in the point.

Answer (score -1):

[image]Thanks for you comment! Maybe I expressed my self wrongly. You're right, it doesn't have to react to physics. In the case of particles, the emitter is being translated, so it leaves a trail.
The problem:
If you look at the rail in the video, it looks as though it was an animted shape, because it appears to have an actual outline, that is being transformed. If I use particles, as the particles get smaller to the end of their lifetimes, there appears a gap to the bigger particles before it, so the outcome looks scattered. It seems to me, there's a problem with the time between each particle emitted, but apparently you can't change that in the Godot Particles2D emitter.

Comment: Don't post comments or additional information as answers. Add the information to your question and remove this "answer". Stack Overflow isn't a normal discussion forum. BTW, the question is pretty broad and I think it would probably be better to use a forum like https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/.

Comment: Please use the edit feature and reserve answers for answers to the question.